# How get ServletContext in ring init function

Tags: clojure, glassfish, ring

I'm using Clojure+Ring to build a web application running on Glassfish 3.
How can I get access to `ServletContext` variable in the Ring `init` function?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

The ServletContext, if any, is available in the request map. I found it useful to look at the values of `:context, :servlet-context` and `:servlet-context-path`. Here's a small ring middleware I use to determine the path:

```
(def ^:dynamic *app-context* nil)

(defn wrap-context [handler]
 (fn [request]
  (when-let [context (:context request)]
    (logging/debug (str "Request with context " context)))
  (when-let [pathdebug (:path-debug request)]
    (logging/debug (str "Request with path-debug " pathdebug)))
  (when-let [servlet-context (:servlet-context request)]
    (logging/debug (str "Request with servlet-context " servlet-context)))
  (when-let [servlet-context-path (:servlet-context-path request)]
    (logging/debug (str "Request with servlet-context-path " servlet-context-path)))
  (binding [*app-context* (str (:context request) "/")]
     (logging/debug (str "Using appcontext " *app-context*))
     (-> request
         handler))))

(defn url-in-context [url]
    (str *app-context* url))
```

Comment: Unfortunately `init` function don't have access to `request` parameter.

Comment: I see you're determining the path here, but not actually calling url-in-context. Shouldn't url-in-context be called from wrap-context (i.e., if you actually want your app to be able to work transparently regardless of where it is)?

Comment: No, `url-in-context` would be used in the app, e.g. within a view-model to construct a link.